# Xmonad: key binding to bring a window from a another workspace to your current workspace

Tags: haskell, key-bindings, xmonad

I am hoping that you folks can help me as I am new to Haskell and Haskell-fu is rather weak.

I am trying to create a quake-like terminal that drops down when called upon. For the most part I figured that storing a named urxvt terminal in layout managed by a `simpleDrawer` (`XMonad.Layout.Drawer`) works well for this. What I am having a problem with is binding a key to it so that it will pop up on whatever workspace I happen to be in.

The `bringSelected` option doesn't work for me as I do not want to have to deal with the grid menu. What I have tried that has gotten me the closest is:

```
raiseMaybe (spawnHere "urxvt -name drawer") (resource =? "drawer")
```

And:

```
ifWindows (resource =? "drawer") (mapM_ focus) (spawn "urxvt -name drawer")
```

The problem is that both essentially do the same thing in that instead of bringing said window (with `resource =? "drawer"`) to my current workspace, it shifts me away from my current workspace to wherever it was last invoked.

Ideally I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
ifWindows (resource =? "drawer") ({- bring window to current workspace -})  
    (spawnHere "urxvt -name drawer")
```

Answer (score 1):

Going over the contrib docs it seems that I am trying to reinvent the wheel as I can just easily use scratchpad. That should do the trick.

But...if anyone has any ideas regarding the question above, i.e. using ifWindows to pull another window from one workspace to another I would love to know how you went about it.

Added the following myKeys:

```
, ("M-`", scratchpadSpawnActionTerminal myScratchTerm)
```

Defined the ManageHook:

```
myScratchPadHook :: ManageHook
myScratchPadHook =
scratchpadManageHook (W.RationalRect fLeft fTop tRight fBottom)   
 where
  fLeft = 0.0
  fTop = 0.75
  tRight = 1.0
  fBottom = 0.25
```

and added

```
<+> myScratchPadHook
```